# Why is a page shown with 'hidden' next to the name in the list of pages if the page is set to public?

Tags: pages

Basically the question is in the title.
I have a few pages where the pages are public and linked to from other pages but in the list of pages it shows hidden. But they are not in the list of hidden pages. Can someone just explain what could be going on? I just want to make sure I'm not restricting pages I don't mean to - this is a legacy site that I've just taken on so there is likely a lot I don't understand yet about it.

(Adding requested screenshots!)
[image: Showing where I'm seeing hidden in the list of pages]

[image: Page itself being public]

Comment: I'm not familiar with any functionality for marking pages as "Hidden" in WordPress. Are you using a plugin for this?

Comment: do you have a screenshot of what you're describing? This isn't something I've seen, and which page list are you referring to? Is this in WP Admin/the dashboard? Or in a widget? block? shortcode? Use the `Edit` link under the tags to improve your question